# Can a runner make a run on an "empty" remote server?

Tags: android-netrunner

A runner has "Bank Job" ( https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01029 ). Can he (or she) make a run on a remote server without any installments (ice, asset, upgrades, agenda)? In other words, can a runner just spend one click to take all the credits from bank job? Reference on the rules will be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, remotes only exist if there is a card installed either inside of them (asset/upgrade/agenda) or in front of them (ICE). This differs from the central servers, which always exist even if there is nothing in or protecting them (e.g., archives).

This is discussed on page 4 of the official FAQ, under "Destruction of Servers" (emphasis mine):

> If there are no cards installed in or protecting a remote server, then
>   **the server immediately ceases to exist**. If a server ceases to exist
>   during a run, the run immediately ends. Unless the run has passed step
>   4.4 of the timing structure of a run, it is not considered to be successful or unsuccessful.